# Can't open port

Tags: centos, postfix, firewall, smtp, selinux

I can't open port 25 and 587. Background information: I am running CentOS 7 with firewalld and httpd. Now I want to run a mailserver. I started with installing postfix. Then I added firewall rules for the ports 25 and 587. This is the output of `iptables -nvL IN_public_allow`:

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination
1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 ctstate NEW
2   112 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 ctstate NEW
```

But I can't use telnet to test postfix. I checked twice with this little tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
SSH, HTTP/HTTPS are open, 25 and 587 are not.

These are two lines of my log:

```
Mar 02 17:53:30 MyServer postfix/smtp[2099]: connect to mydomain.com[fdd6:7e90:ec71:be65:b3d]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 02 17:53:30 MyServer postfix/smtp[2099]: connect to mydomain.com[4.2.67.123]:25: Connection refused
```

What is my problem? I thought of SELinux. How can I investigate this further?

Comment: open `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, check order of your rules, make sure you're allowing before deny or reject.

Comment: Opening the firewall is not enough. You have to actually _start_ the mail server!

Comment: @alexus This file is empty.
@MichaelHampton Postfix IS running. `systemctl status postfix` looks good

Comment: @LuMa try `service iptables save` and then look into that file.

Comment: @LuMa also try `netstat -tan | grep '\:25.*LISTEN'` and see if your ports are actually listens for connection as well.

Comment: `service iptables save` doesn't work: "The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl." using `systemctl` doesn't work either.

`netstat -tan | grep '\:25.*LISTEN'` outputs this: http://pastebin.com/Wukig0Vj

Answer (score 0):

take a look at configuration portion of [HowTos/postfix - CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix), as per your pastebin your postfix isn't listening for outside connection..

`service` works for me, although I know they replaced it with `systemctl`

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# service iptables save
iptables: Nothing to save.                                 [WARNING]
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]#
```

Comment: Are you on CentOS 7?

Comment: I'm using: `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`